# Is this normal? Ubuntu 14.04 Gnome 3.9.90?

Tags: gnome, updates

I just finished installing Ubuntu 14.04 and Gnome Shell `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop`, however when I checked what version has been installed I read 3.9.90: is this correct?

Isn't Ubuntu 14.04 supposed to ship with gnome 3.10 at least? What am I missing?

Comment: Where are you seeing "3.9.90" at exactly?

Comment: I use three different tools to find out the Gnome version: sysinfo: 3.8.4; I-Nex: 3.9.90; gnome-sessions --version: 3.9.90. None of them points to the 3.10. What can i do to have at least the 3.10?

Comment: I don't know what "sysinfo" and "I-Nex" are, but GNOME 3.10 is included in 14.04, yes.

Answer (score 1):

The package `gnome-session` being `3.9.90` is still *GNOME 3.10*. It is simply a release or two before the final 3.10 upstream release, which almost certainly had no changes from the 3.9.90 release. GNOME is comprised of many upstream source packages, and their versions may not always be exactly the same, even for a particular release of GNOME itself, in the same way that every package in *Ubuntu 14.04* is not versioned as 14.04.

So yes, it is normal, and yes, Ubuntu 14.04 does include GNOME 3.10.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like its just a minor issue. Take a look in [here](http://www.linuxdescomplicado.com.br/2014/04/saiba-como-instalar-o-gnome-312-no.html) and [here](http://ubuntugnome.org/).